# UseState() is not updating on Button's onClick Method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm very naive to ReactJS, in below code, in columns editorCellRenderer, there is a button onClick function, which uses rowsData of useState, so after fetching data from api, I update
rowsData using setRowsData, but in button rowsData always remains []. Because of this after edit of any column data, it is not reflected in UI.

section of code I'm referring:

```
 <button
            style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 20 }}
            onClick={async (e) => {
              console.log({ rowsData });
              let rowsClone = [...rowsData];
              let updatedRowIndex = rowsClone.findIndex(
                (r) => r.id === data.id
              );
              rowsClone[updatedRowIndex] = data;
              setRowsData(rowsClone);
              tableManager.rowEditApi.setEditRowId(null);
            }}
          >
            &#x2714;
          </button>
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GridTable from "@nadavshaar/react-grid-table";
// import data from "./data.json";
import "./styles.css";

const convertData = (response, from = 0) => {
  const rawData = response.data.nutritionData.data;
  return rawData.map((raw, index) => {
    const obj = {
      id: from + index + 1,
      _id: raw._id,
      Index: from + index + 1,
      ENERC_KCAL: raw.ENERC_KCAL.qty,
      totalWeight: raw.totalWeight.qty,
      FAT: raw.macro_nutrients.FAT.qty,
      FASAT: raw.macro_nutrients.FASAT.qty,
      FATRN: raw.macro_nutrients.FATRN.qty,
      CHOCDF: raw.macro_nutrients.CHOCDF.qty,
      FIBTG: raw.macro_nutrients.FIBTG.qty,
      SUGAR: raw.macro_nutrients.SUGAR.qty,
      PROCNT: raw.macro_nutrients.PROCNT.qty,
      CHOLE: raw.micro_nutrients.CHOLE.qty,
      NA: raw.micro_nutrients.NA.qty,
      CA: raw.micro_nutrients.CA.qty,
      MG: raw.micro_nutrients.MG.qty,
      K: raw.micro_nutrients.K.qty,
      FE: raw.micro_nutrients.FE.qty,
      ZN: raw.micro_nutrients.ZN.qty,
      P: raw.micro_nutrients.P.qty,
      VITA_IU: raw.micro_nutrients.VITA_IU.qty,
      VITC: raw.micro_nutrients.VITC.qty,
      THIA: raw.micro_nutrients.THIA.qty,
      RIBF: raw.micro_nutrients.RIBF.qty,
      NIA: raw.micro_nutrients.NIA.qty,
      VITB6A: raw.micro_nutrients.VITB6A.qty,
      VITB12: raw.micro_nutrients.VITB12.qty,
      VITD: raw.micro_nutrients.VITD.qty,
      TOCPHA: raw.micro_nutrients.TOCPHA.qty,
      VITK1: raw.micro_nutrients.VITK1.qty,
      healthLabels: raw.healthLabels,
      cautions: raw.cautions,
      brand: raw.brand,
      title: raw.title
    };
    return obj;
  })
}


const AsyncTable = () => {
  let [rowsData, setRowsData] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    {
      id: 0,
      field: "Index",
      label: "Index",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 31,
      field: "title",
      label: "title",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      field: "ENERC_KCAL",
      label: "ENERC_KCAL",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      field: "totalWeight",
      label: "totalWeight",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      field: "FAT",
      label: "FAT",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      field: "FASAT",
      label: "FASAT",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      field: "FATRN",
      label: "FATRN",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      field: "CHOCDF",
      label: "CHOCDF",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      field: "FIBTG",
      label: "FIBTG",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      field: "SUGAR",
      label: "SUGAR",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      field: "PROCNT",
      label: "PROCNT",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      field: "CHOLE",
      label: "CHOLE",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      field: "NA",
      label: "NA",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      field: "CA",
      label: "CA",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      field: "MG",
      label: "MG",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      field: "K",
      label: "K",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      field: "FE",
      label: "FE",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 16,
      field: "ZN",
      label: "ZN",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 17,
      field: "P",
      label: "P",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 18,
      field: "VITA_IU",
      label: "VITA_IU",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 19,
      field: "VITC",
      label: "VITC",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 20,
      field: "THIA",
      label: "THIA",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 21,
      field: "RIBF",
      label: "RIBF",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 22,
      field: "NIA",
      label: "NIA",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 23,
      field: "VITB6A",
      label: "VITB6A",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 24,
      field: "VITB12",
      label: "VITB12",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 25,
      field: "VITD",
      label: "VITD",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 26,
      field: "TOCPHA",
      label: "TOCPHA",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 27,
      field: "VITK1",
      label: "VITK1",
      width: "max-content"
    },
    {
      id: 28,
      field: "healthLabels",
      label: "healthLabels"
    },
    {
      id: 29,
      field: "cautions",
      label: "cautions"
    },
    {
      id: 30,
      field: "brand",
      label: "brand"
    },

    {
      id: "my-buttons-column",
      width: "max-content",
      pinned: true,
      sortable: false,
      resizable: false,
      cellRenderer: ({
        tableManager,
        value,
        data,
        column,
        colIndex,
        rowIndex
      }) => (
        <button
          style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
          onClick={(e) => tableManager.rowEditApi.setEditRowId(data.id)}
        >
          &#x270E;
        </button>
      ),
      editorCellRenderer: ({
        tableManager,
        value,
        data,
        column,
        colIndex,
        rowIndex,
        onChange
      }) => (
        <div style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
          <button
            style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
            onClick={(e) => tableManager.rowEditApi.setEditRowId(null)}
          >
            &#x2716;
          </button>
          <button
            style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 20 }}
            onClick={async (e) => {
              console.log({ rowsData });
              let rowsClone = [...rowsData];
              let updatedRowIndex = rowsClone.findIndex(
                (r) => r.id === data.id
              );
              rowsClone[updatedRowIndex] = data;
              setRowsData(rowsClone);
              tableManager.rowEditApi.setEditRowId(null);
            }}
          >
            &#x2714;
          </button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  ]

  const onRowsRequest = async (requestData, tableManager) => {

    const limit = requestData.to - requestData.from;
    const page = Math.floor(requestData.from / limit) + 1;

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v0/noauth/get/nutrition', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        limit,
        page
      })
    });

    const jsonData = await response.json();
    const rows = convertData(jsonData, requestData.from);
    const totalRows = jsonData.data.nutritionData.totalDocuments;
    setRowsData(rows);

    return {
      rows,
      totalRows
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GridTable
        pageSizes={[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100]}
        columns={columns} onRowsRequest={onRowsRequest} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AsyncTable;
```

App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

data.json to mimic actual api data:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": "0000",
    "data": {
        "nutritionData": {
            "totalDocuments": 667888,
            "totalPages": 66789,
            "data": [
                {
                    "ENERC_KCAL": {
                        "code": 208,
                        "label": "Energy",
                        "qty": 2905.88,
                        "unit": "kcal"
                    },
                    "totalWeight": {
                        "label": "weight",
                        "qty": 1906.75,
                        "unit": "g"
                    },
                    "_id": "ea553309-53ee-41dd-8a87-b1a7aa138e72",
                    "macro_nutrients": {
                        "FAT": {
                            "code": 204,
                            "label": "TOTAL_Fat",
                            "qty": 181.32,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        "FASAT": {
                            "code": 606,
                            "label": "Saturated",
                            "qty": 92.62,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        "FATRN": {
                            "code": 605,
                            "label": "Trans",
                            "qty": 4.8,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        "CHOCDF": {
                            "code": 205,
                            "label": "Carbs",
                            "qty": 220.47,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        "FIBTG": {
                            "code": 291,
                            "label": "Fiber",
                            "qty": 16.96,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        "SUGAR": {
                            "code": 269,
                            "label": "Sugars",
                            "qty": 43.6,
                            "unit": "g"
                        },
                        "PROCNT": {
                            "code": 203,
                            "label": "Protein",
                            "qty": 98.03,
                            "unit": "g"
                        }
                    },
                    "micro_nutrients": {
                        "CHOLE": {
                            "code": 601,
                            "label": "Cholesterol",
                            "qty": 427.81,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "NA": {
                            "code": 307,
                            "label": "Sodium",
                            "qty": 2874.8,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "CA": {
                            "code": 301,
                            "label": "Calcium",
                            "qty": 2401.52,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "MG": {
                            "code": 304,
                            "label": "Magnesium",
                            "qty": 293.34,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "K": {
                            "code": 306,
                            "label": "Potassium",
                            "qty": 3371.02,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "FE": {
                            "code": 303,
                            "label": "Iron",
                            "qty": 4.28,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "ZN": {
                            "code": 309,
                            "label": "Zinc",
                            "qty": 13.51,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "P": {
                            "code": 305,
                            "label": "Phosphorus",
                            "qty": 2288.82,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "VITA_IU": {
                            "code": 318,
                            "label": "Vitamin A",
                            "qty": 3073.58,
                            "unit": "iu"
                        },
                        "VITC": {
                            "code": 401,
                            "label": "Vitamin C",
                            "qty": 24.98,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "THIA": {
                            "code": 404,
                            "label": "Thiamin (B1)",
                            "qty": 1.02,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "RIBF": {
                            "code": 405,
                            "label": "Riboflavin (B2)",
                            "qty": 2.35,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "NIA": {
                            "code": 406,
                            "label": "Niacin (B3)",
                            "qty": 13.12,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "VITB6A": {
                            "code": 415,
                            "label": "Vitamin B6",
                            "qty": 1.78,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "VITB12": {
                            "code": 418,
                            "label": "Vitamin B12",
                            "qty": 4.95,
                            "unit": "mcg"
                        },
                        "VITD": {
                            "code": 324,
                            "label": "Vitamin D",
                            "qty": 368.7,
                            "unit": "mcg"
                        },
                        "TOCPHA": {
                            "code": 323,
                            "label": "Vitamin E",
                            "qty": 9.81,
                            "unit": "mg"
                        },
                        "VITK1": {
                            "code": 430,
                            "label": "Vitamin K",
                            "qty": 42.5,
                            "unit": "mcg"
                        }
                    },
                    "healthLabels": [
                        "FISH_FREE",
                        "RED_MEAT_FREE",
                        "PEANUT_FREE",
                        "MUSTARD_FREE",
                        "GLUTEN_FREE",
                        "SESAME_FREE",
                        "SOY_FREE",
                        "TREE_NUT_FREE"
                    ],
                    "cautions": [
                        "DAIRY"
                    ],
                    "supported_serving_units": [
                        {
                            "label": "serving",
                            "unit_weight": "263.0",
                            "qty": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "grams",
                            "unit_weight": 1,
                            "qty": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "ingredients": [
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "cups milk",
                                "qty": [
                                    "2",
                                    "1/2"
                                ]
                            },
                            "ingredient": "milk",
                            "unit": "cup",
                            "qty": 2.5,
                            "matched_ingredient": "milk",
                            "weight": 610,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 19.215,
                                "fat": 19.825,
                                "carbs": 29.279999999999998,
                                "sodium": 262.3
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "cups water",
                                "qty": [
                                    "1",
                                    "1/2"
                                ]
                            },
                            "ingredient": "water",
                            "unit": "cup",
                            "qty": 1.5,
                            "matched_ingredient": "water",
                            "weight": 360,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 0,
                                "fat": 0,
                                "carbs": 0,
                                "sodium": 14.4
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "cup butter",
                                "qty": [
                                    "1/4"
                                ]
                            },
                            "ingredient": "butter",
                            "unit": "cup",
                            "qty": 0.25,
                            "matched_ingredient": "butter",
                            "weight": 56.75,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 0.482375,
                                "fat": 46.029925,
                                "carbs": 0.03405,
                                "sodium": 364.9025
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "mashed potatoes 1 box",
                                "qty": []
                            },
                            "ingredient": "potatoes",
                            "unit": "box",
                            "qty": 1,
                            "matched_ingredient": "potato",
                            "weight": 100,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 2.02,
                                "fat": 0.09,
                                "carbs": 17.47,
                                "sodium": 6
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "can kernel corn",
                                "qty": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            },
                            "ingredient": "kernel corn",
                            "unit": "can",
                            "qty": 1,
                            "matched_ingredient": "corn kernel",
                            "weight": 300,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 10.86,
                                "fat": 4.26,
                                "carbs": 77.61,
                                "sodium": 12
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "cup cheddar cheese",
                                "qty": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            },
                            "ingredient": "cheddar cheese",
                            "unit": "cup",
                            "qty": 1,
                            "matched_ingredient": "cheddar cheese",
                            "weight": 240,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 57.696,
                                "fat": 81.16799999999999,
                                "carbs": 3.192,
                                "sodium": 1545.6
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "input": {
                                "text": "cup French fried onions",
                                "qty": [
                                    "1"
                                ]
                            },
                            "ingredient": "french fried onions",
                            "unit": "cup",
                            "qty": 1,
                            "matched_ingredient": "french fries",
                            "weight": 240,
                            "nutrition": {
                                "protein": 7.752,
                                "fat": 29.951999999999998,
                                "carbs": 92.88000000000001,
                                "sodium": 669.6
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "source": "food.com",
                    "brand": "",
                    "img_url": [],
                    "title": "crunchy onion potato bake",
                    "actualTitle": "Crunchy Onion Potato Bake",
                    "url": "http://www.food.com/recipe/crunchy-onion-potato-bake-479149",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-06-22T06:51:01.844Z"
                }]
                
    "displayMessage": "Successful"
}
```

I tried using useEffect and update button onClick function whenever state of rowsData changes. It didnt work.

I'm expecting to have rowsData in button onClick to be changed when I fetch api data and setRowsData in api call.

Comment: have you used `useEffect(() => {console.log(rowsData)}, [rowsData])` with rowsData in dependency Array ?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(updatedRowIndex)` before `rowsClone[updatedRowIndex] = data;` to make sure this is working?

Comment: @NikhilGaur you don't use an effect for this

Comment: @AhmedSbai i know but i was just trying to check because as we know setState works asynchronously so it takes some time to update than it will not print the result. So it's better to check it with useEffect whether the state is updated or not

Comment: @NikhilGaur From the question, what I understood, the issue is that `rowsData` is `[]` when he tries to access its value from the event handler therefore `rowsClone` is always `[]`

Comment: @AhmedSbai correct

Comment: @JalakPatoliya the suggestion in my answer does not work as well?

Comment: @AhmedSbai it totally worked bro, thanks a lot :) I made one more change, in GridTable i passed rows = {rowsData}, then it reflected perfectly on table, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update a state based on its previous value, better is to do it with the functional state update:

```js
setRowsData((prev) =>
  prev.map((row) => {
    if (row.id === data.id) {
      return data;
    } else {
      return row;
    }
  })
)
```

this way `prev` will always provide you with the current value of the state, and what you return is what you give as a new value to it. here we return an array from `prev` mapping through each element returning `data` if the condition is met, `row` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Though answer by @AhmedSbai totally worked fine and I found it better than solution provided by chatgpt, just for information I want to show solution given by chatGPT, after trying 30+ solutions and wasting 2-3 days, only one worked for me.

In Async Table:
` const rowsDataRef = useRef(rowsData);

```
useEffect(() => {
    rowsDataRef.current = rowsData;
}, [rowsData]);`
```

In editorCellRenderer:

```
onClick={async (e) => {
  let rowsClone = [...rowsDataRef.current];
  let updatedRowIndex = rowsClone.findIndex(
      (r) => r.id === data.id
  );
  rowsClone[updatedRowIndex] = data;

  setRowsData(rowsClone);
  tableManager.rowEditApi.setEditRowId(null);
}
```

Comment: this is ok for this example , here, each time `rowsData` is updated you update `rowsDataRef ` and you always have the latest version of `rowsData` and you use `rowsDataRef ` instead  **but it will not for a case** when state gets multiple updates before the component rerenders and `rowsDataRef` is updated so you want always to use the functional state update with `prev`